# Polynomial regression in R with multiple independent variables

Tags: r

I want to do a polynomial regression in R with one dependent variable `y` and two independent variables `x1` and `x2`. In my mind the model should look as follows,

`y=b0 + b1x1+ b2x2+ b3x1^2+ b4x2^2+ b5x1x2`

I tried `lm(y~x1+x2+poly(x1,2,raw=TRUE)+poly(x2,2,raw=TRUE))` and also `lm(y~x1+x2+I(x1^2)+I(x2^2))`. But this only gives the squares and not the product of the two variables.

I can of cause do `lm(y~x1+ x2+ x1^2+ x2^2+ x1x2)`. But i would like to know whether there is a much easier way than to write the whole equation out. I also would like to do to the power of 3 and 4 models which is more lengthy.

Comment: You can add the interaction with: `lm(y~poly(x1,2)+poly(x2,2)+x1:x2, dd)`. Is that what you're after?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you can use **polym**

```
y ~ polym(x1, x2, degree=2, raw=TRUE) # is equivalent to
y ~ x1 + x2 + I(x1^2) + I(x2^2) + x1:x2
```

But be careful with the order of the coefficients they are not the same as the second formula.

If you use **degree=3** then it will add interactions of higher order like this **I(x1^2):x2 +I(x2^2):x1**, thus you have to adapt your formula.

NB : **polym** is a wrapper for **poly**, so you can use this latter with the same call.