# R: quadratic regression all factors: how to specify a formula?

Tags: r, formula, lm, quadratic

I would like to specify a quadratic regression on all available factors on a dataset with linear, pairwise interaction and quadratic terms. In an example, if I have

```
y<-rnorm(1000)
A<-sample(1:4,1000,replace=TRUE)
B<-sample(1:2,1000,replace=TRUE)
C<-sample(1:10,1000,replace=TRUE)
Dataset<-data.frame(y,A,B,C)
```

And if I would like to regress `y` on all of my factors in this fashion I would like to have a model like

```
model<-lm(y~.+.^2+I(A^2)+I(B^2)+I(C^2),data=Dataset)
```

but I would like to know whether there is an expression that specifies all quadratic terms from all factors so I do not have to specify all `I(A^2)+I(B^2)+I(C^2)`.

I have tried

```
model<-lm(y~.+.^2+I(.^2),data=Dataset)
```

and it does not work. Can you help me on this one?
Thank you.

Comment: Hi, you can use wisely the **poly** function, and you should take a look at this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28729512/polynomial-regression-in-r-with-multiple-independent-variables/28730674#28730674) for more details.

Comment: Isn't model<-lm(y~.^2,data=Dataset) sufficient?

Comment: @duffymo specifying multiple variables to the square without the Identity() operator is interpreted as "all single factors and all 2nd degree interactions".

Comment: Yes, that's how I read the requirement: "I would like to specify a quadratic regression on all available factors on a dataset with linear, pairwise interaction and quadratic terms"

Comment: @duffymo so all the quadratic terms are still missing, that's the op's problem since I(.^2) is not a valid term

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a direct solution so i come up with a way to reconstruct your formula. That works for any number of variables:

```
library(dplyr)
data <- mtcars
y    <- "cyl"
formula <-  paste0("I(", names(data)[names(data)!=y], "^2)+", collapse="") %>%
  paste(y, "~", .) %>%
  substr(., 1, nchar(.)-1) %>%
  as.formula
lm(data=mtcars, formula)
```

You can modify it to include single factors and interactions. The dplyr library is here just for the clarity of the script (%>% operator)

Comment: I cannot write the formula you have suggested: `Error in nchar(.) : object '.' not found`

Comment: I don't reproduce the error. Have you loaded the package?

Comment: Yes, I did. I have just installed it today and I re-ran once again and the same error message appeared. I am using R 3.0.3 and platform x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit). Might that justify the difference in output?

Comment: Yes it's what causes the error. I tried to load your version of R and i also get the error. Probably the ability to reuse the '.' operator several times in a line was nos implemented yet.

Comment: you can replace the second dot with the repetition of the whole upper lines `paste(y, "~", paste0("I(", names(data)[names(data)!=y], "^2)+", collapse=""))`  Or you can rewrite it in base R... ;-)